# Ad Hoc network with three ir more devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-wifi, adhoc, wifi-direct

On a bunch of android devices (>3), is it possible to form an ad hoc network where every phone can discover each other? I am working with 4.0+, so can use Bluetooth, WiFi, or WiFi Direct.
Previously asked questions that I managed to lookup seem to suggest either
1. Go root the device, and change config files, etc to enable ad hoc networking
2. Set up one device as access point, and make the others connect to it.

1 is not generic, 2 is not suitable to the kind of application I envision. What I'd like is, if A,B and C are the devices, they can all discover and do data transfer with each other. Can the two happen in parallel?